# should be mapped with insert="false" update="false"

Tags: java, hibernate

I got the next 2 classes :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="questions")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="is_sponsered")
@SequenceGenerator(name="id_seq")
  public class Question {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="id_seq")
protected int id;

@Column(name="is_sponsered",nullable=false)
protected boolean sponsered=false;

....}
```

and a subclass :

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("true")

public class SP extends Question{

public SP(String q)
{
    super(q);
    this.sponsered=true;
}
```

However, I'm getting the next error :

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: SP column: is_sponsered
```

From what I understood insertable=false and updatble=false is often used when we have a OneToMany relation. In this case it's just inheritance. When adding the insertabl=false,updtable=false to the column sponsored in the Question class the error doesn't appear. I wanted to understand why.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you need to map the discriminator column, you'll have to map it with `insert="false" update="false"` because it is only Hibernate that manages the column. If you don't map the column, Hibernate considers it declared once, for inner purposes. If you declare it, that's twice, hence the error.

Comment: but both my subclass and my parent class should insert that value, in case it is the subclass the value should be true and in case it is the parent it should be false.

Comment: @JeyJ That's not correct, the only way to set the value is through `@DiscriminatorValue`.

Comment: But if i want to update an object of the base class (set the sponsered to true) I will get an error because update=false. How can I handle that ?

Comment: @JeyJ Place DiscriminatorValue also on base class.

Comment: But in case I have an object of the parent class and I want to change the value of the discriminator column in that object(from false to true). I wont be able to change it because of the updatble=false  setting.

Comment: @JeyJ You can't do it also because it would break the discriminator contract (all instances must have the same discriminator value)

Comment: In my case, I have entity with annotation because was used in other project, now I'm used the same entity in new project with xml mapping, where I should this insert="false" update="false"???

Answer (score 1):

This is because `sponsered` columns in `SP` is already mapped by `@DiscriminatorValue` which should always equal to "true" .

If you map `sponsered` columns twice for update/insert , Hibernate will get confused as it does not know which values should it use for update /insert . But after you change `sponsered` column to read-only mode (i.e. `insertabl=false` ,`updtable=false`) , hibernate knows what values should it use for update / insert as there is only single source of truth.

Comment: but both my subclass and my parent class should insert that value, in case it is the subclass the value should be true and in case it is the parent it should be false.